# Server 2012 shared folder with 2 mapped drives

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, mappeddrive

I have a program that requires a shared folder with 2 drive letters to it. How can I create this? If I map the drives - both pointing to the shared folder, they both have different drive letters but the same name: Example of what I want is below:

shared folder:

D:\SharedFolder

Mapped Drives:

G:\Applied

H:\Tam_Data

If I map them by clicking on map drives, it creates the map, but if I rename G:\Applied, then H:\ also becomes H:\Applied. I also tried adding this in Group policy with a label, but it just gives me the shared folder name.

I am lost, been at this for hours. Thanks

Comment: It really isn't clear to me what you are asking about here, or what you are expecting.  If you access the same share from two locations, then a rename content in the share will apply for any way you access it.

Comment: This makes no sense. What software requires two different drive letters mapped to the same shared folder?

Comment: Ew, but on the server make `D:\SharedFolder`, share it. Make `D:\SharedFolder\Applied`. Download [SysInternals Junction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) and make a junction `D:\SharedFolder\Tam_Data` pointing to `D:\SharedFolder\Applied`. Map G: and H: to `\\server\sharedfolder` from the client. Forget you did this and think they are separate folders, delete one, lose both, data loss hilarity. Forget some backup software can't handle it, broken software hilarity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks TessellatingHeckler, that made me think better and found a solution.

I know this makes no sense, but the way Applied Systems TAM works is that it needs a drive G: for its programs and H: for its data ( yet they both have to be in the same drive with a shared folder = D:\Applied )

To fix this with creating a mapped drive, I had to share the D:\Applied folder twice under Properties, Advanced sharing, share it as Applied and the Add another share as TamData

Then I can just map the drives as

G:\Applied
H:\Tam_data

that way everything is pointing to the same shared folder of D:\Applied

Thanks for all the responses, it was simple, but my brain could not comprehend it at first.